# Is there a fast probabilistic algorithm for number of mutual things between users?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, spatial, bloom-filter

E.g. assume there's users, groups, and a many-to-many relationship between them. Assume there are millions of users, thousands of groups, and billions of user-group relationships.

Given a user, I want to sort the other users by the number of mutual groups between them. Doing it naively would be way too slow. I think caching the number of mutual groups for every pair of users is the most common approach, but caching n^2 user pairs would still be expensive (even if I only store non-zero pairs). I'm wondering if there's a probabilistic way to do this efficiently.

I'm not too familiar with Bloom filters, but if I generated Bloom filters for each user representing the groups they're in, I think I can use this for sorting users by number of mutual groups. I can XOR the given user's Bloom filters with every other user's Bloom filters, then sort by the number of 0s in the resulting bit arrays. If 2 users joined the identical groups, then they would have identical Bloom filters, so the XOR would produce all 0s. The issue is this would require a table scan, I don't think indexes would help.

Another way I can think of is abusing spatial indexes. E.g. if there are N groups, then in an N-dimensional space, a user's vector's nth value is 1 if they're in the nth group, and 0 otherwise. Then, I would use dimensionality reduction. 2 users with many mutual groups should be closer in the reduced space. The issue is:

- if I have many dimensions in the reduced space, it'll be expensive to store
- if I have few dimensions, there won't be enough signal to be useful

Is there a better algorithm for approximating the number of mutual things between users?

Comment: Do you actually need all-pairs overlaps or just the (approximate) closest other users for each user? If the latter, you could use locality-sensitive hashing (e.g., MinHash) or wedge sampling.

Comment: If there are not so many users but they have a lot of groups, it's also possible to modify HyperLogLog to support approximate intersection counting.

Comment: Approximate closest other user is sufficient. I read a bit about MinHash and wedge sampling, but I don't see how they could be applied here. I don't think users would join enough groups to make either methods work. E.g. if each user joins 100/1000000 groups, the hashes wouldn't produce enough signal. If they were to join half of all groups (which they wouldn't), then it would be more useful. Am I missing something?

Comment: The point of those methods is that they don't really care how many other groups other users are in. See https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3038912.3052633, which scaled these techniques to the Twitter follower graph, with tens of billions of edges.

Comment: Thanks @DavidEisenstat, that's a really interesting paper. Seems like the gist of these techniques is computing a vector for each user, then doing cosine similarity. That should work for me, though it's a bit complicated. I'll start a bounty to see if there's anything else.

Comment: For using LSH you create buckets of very similar users. Then you perform the scan, but just over the elements in the same bucket, which is still O(N), but with an smaller N. Then consider pagination: the most similar would be in the same bucket, but where are the others? Start looking for the users in buckets with a hash that differs in 1 bit, then 2 bits, then 3...
Also, consider that scanning a list of hashes and performing xor and popcount is very fast. Millions per second fast even in 10 years old hardware.

Comment: This is not a confident answer but maybe https://github.com/spotify/annoy, approximate NN algorithm might do the trick. But this assumes that each user has a vector of binary values indicating the groups it likes ie u1:[1,1,0,1....], u2:[0,1,1...].